# Get props in action -> reducer -> costum function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I have a component which is the "base" for another component. I want to add some more functionality to the newly created component

```
<SomeComponent
onSelect = { this.props.handleSelect }
onDeselect = { this.props.handleDeselect }
selectionList = { valuesList }
value = { values }
origin = "XYZ" />
```

`onSelect` triggeres the action `this.props.handleSelect`

```
export function handleSelect(value) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(actionCreator(HANDLE_SELECT, value));
    }
}
```

That actions goes into the `reducer`

```
case HANDLE_SELECT: {
    const newValues = value_select(state, action);
        return {
            ...state,
            find: {
                ...state.a, 
                values: newValues
            }
        }
 }
```

Finally, `value_select` is called to do all the magic

```
export const value_select = function(state, action) {
    ...

    const newData = {
    XYZ: action.payload
    }
    return newData
}
```

How would I mage the `"a"` from the `props`  from my `component` acessible in `value_select()`. I need it where the `XYZ` is...
Please note that I cannot write anything into the `onSelect`, hence the `onClick` event. I am using a predesigned `component` which I dont want to alter. Only the `components` that are based on the original one.

Comment: you want to pass `origin` prop from `SomeComponent` to value_select, right ?

Comment: @GrzegorzMotyl thats right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another handler inside `SomeComponent` and add new argument with prop you want to pass to original `handleSelect`. If `SomeComponent` is from vendor and you can't change it's code, than you will have to wrap it

```
class BetterComponent extends React.Component{
handleSelect = (value) {
    this.props.handleSelect(value, this.props.origin)
}

render() {
   return (
      <SomeComponent
        ...this.props
        onSelect = { this.handleSelect }
      />
   )
}
```

Add new param to your handle select

```
export function handleSelect(value, origin) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(actionCreator(HANDLE_SELECT, {
           value: value,
           origin: origin
        }));
    }
}
```

Then origin will be accessible by `action.payload.origin` inside `value_select`

Of course now you have to call `BetterComponent` instead of `SomeComponent`

```
<BetterComponent
onSelect = { this.props.handleSelect }
onDeselect = { this.props.handleDeselect }
selectionList = { valuesList }
value = { values }
origin = "XYZ" />
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be  `class BetterComponent extends someComponent{` instead of `React.Component`? And then here `render() {
   return (
      <SomeComponent` rather this `render() {
   return (
      <BetterComponent` ?

Comment: Inheritance in JS is tricky , I think it's better to use wrapper like I did instead of inheritance (Composition over Inheritance - clean code rule ;) )

Comment: `BetterComponent` returns `SomeComponent` on render, just with changed onSelect prop

Comment: Ok. Would I have to repeat in `render() {
   return (
      <SomeComponent
        ...this.props
        onSelect = { this.handleSelect }
      />
   )
}` my whole component ` someComponent` ? All the methods?

Comment: Nope those will be handled by `SomeComponent` itself